# Paired t-test; how to find t-statistic of a given ratio

Tags: excel

I have spent hours in Excel today trying to figure this out but to no avail. I appreciate help on this.

I have a ratio for two responses A and B

> A/B = 17/15 = 1.133

and I want to find the t-statistic for the null hypothesis that the ratio A/B is equal to 1, the null hypothesis being:

> H(subscript 0) = 1

The t-statistic is supposed to be 0.534. I have tried to plot various numbers into this formula:

> (1.133 - 1) / [Std/root(n)]

but I have done something wrong. Should the numbers A and B (17 and 15) be sufficient to calculate the t-stat? If it matters, the total number of observations for my data is 252.

Comment: How do you know that "the t-statistic is supposed to be 0.534"? What is the value for Std? What is your data workflow? Do you start with 252 values each of A/B, then find the average and StDev of those values?

Comment: The t-statistic is 0.534. This number might be an approximation, but as this number is stated in a book, I am assuming it is right.

Of 252 respondents, 17 people gave response A, and 15 people gave response B. I need to find out if the respons ratio (A/B=1.13333) is statistically significant to 1.